# WPF - Command in datacontext of the window and commandparameter from listview in user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I am having a little trouble getting the bindings of a command working in my WPF-application, following the MVVM pattern.

What I currently have:

MainWindow with DataContext MainWindowViewModel.
SecondPage (user control) with DataContext SecondPageViewmodel.

The user control only simply contains a listview called StudentListView binding to an observable collection in SecondPageViewModel.

The main window has a textbox where pressing the enter key will trigger my command, called ReturnPressCommand which is located in the MainWindowViewModel. The main window also contains an instance of the SecondPage user control.

What I would like to do is be able to use the StudentListView from the user control as my command parameter for the command ReturnPressCommand in my Main window.

How do I accomplish this?

The main window:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMTEST.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMTEST.ViewModels"
        xmlns:control="clr-namespace:MVVMTEST.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1600" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="120" Height="20">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Return" 
                            Command="{Binding Path=ReturnPressCommand}" 
                            CommandParameter="{}"/>
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>

        <control:SecondPage x:Name="SecondPageX" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="auto" Visibility="Visible"></control:SecondPage>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The viewmodel for the main window

```cs
using MVVMTEST.Commands;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MVVMTEST.ViewModels
{
    class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            
        }

        private ICommand _returnPressCommand = null;
        public ICommand ReturnPressCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_returnPressCommand == null)
                    _returnPressCommand = new ReturnPressCommand();
                return _returnPressCommand;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The command I want to execute

```cs
namespace MVVMTEST.Commands
{
    class ReturnPressCommand : CommandBase
    {
        public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            // Do operations with the observable collection
        }
    }
}
```

The user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMTEST.Views.SecondPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMTEST.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="1600">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:SecondPageViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid Background="Green">
        <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="StudentListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Gpa}" Header="Gpa"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The viewmodel for the user control

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using MVVMTEST.Models;

namespace MVVMTEST.ViewModels
{
    public class SecondPageViewModel
    {
        public IList<Student> Students { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        public SecondPageViewModel()
        {
            Students.Add(new Student { Name = "Firstname Lastname", Age = 25, Gpa = 0.0 });
        }
    }
}
```

I want the textbox to be visible at all times, however in the future I am planning on adding more user controls and their visibility will change depending on what the user is doing in the application. Right now I want to implement a search feature to filter the students in the observable collection located in the viewmodel for the user control. The user control will then list these filtered students.

Comment: You mean you want to use observable collection of SecondPageViewModel in your command parameter? You already have an instance of it in your MainViewModel. Why can't you use that instead?

Comment: Excactly the observable collection is in the SecondPageViewModel, however I should clarify that the main window contains the user control only in XAML not in the MainWindowViewModel like: <control:SecondPage x:Name="SecondPageX" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="auto" Visibility="Visible"></control:SecondPage>

Comment: User control has nothing to do with this. It is bound to an observable collection which is what you want. Why are you focusing on that User Control?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is split up the command and the commandparameter into different files. The MainWindow has my textbox where I check for the enter key press. The command that gets executed is in the MainWindowViewModel and the collection I want to do operations with is in the SecondPageViewModel. I then want to list this collection in the SecondPage.

Comment: You are not making a lot of sense here but I will try to explain this to you. When you change (add delete update or create) in your observable collection then UI will update automatically. You don't have to pass that as a parameter. Just do operations on the list and the UI will pick up those changes. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Sorry for doing a poor job explaining my issue. Yes I know how the observable collection functions. I want to send in the observable collection to my commands execute method as a parameter. Inside this command is where I will do changes to the collection. However the command is triggered in my main window and the collection is in the viewmodel for my user control. How do I access that collection from my main window?

Comment: Its ok. Your command should be in View model and NOT window. Your main window data context is main view model from there you can access the collection. Also you need to show us your code. Because I am guessing at this point.

Comment: I have added my code and tried to explain a bit better what exactly I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the CommandParameter to the collection via the name of the usercontrol.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="120" Height="20">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Return" 
                            Command="{Binding Path=ReturnPressCommand}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.Students, ElementName=SecondPageX}" />
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you! This does seem to work. A small issue is that DataContext.Students is underlined and has the message: Cannot resolve property 'Students' in data context of type 'MVVMTEST.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel'. Any ideas? It works fine otherwise.